# Resize a ctypes Structure

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to dynamically resize a ctypes structure field:

```
from ctypes import *

class a(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('first', c_ubyte*10), ('second', c_ubyte*20)]
```

Now let's say I need 'second' to be 100 bytes instead of 20. I tried the following:

```
class b(a):
    _fields_ = [('second', c_ubyte*100)]
```

Which appears to work:

```
b.second
<Field type=c_ubyte_Array_100, ofs=30, size=100>
```

The problem is that all it has done is added the 100 element array to the end of b:

```
sizeof(b) #want this to be 110
130

c = b()
addressof(c.second) - addressof(c) #want this to be 10
30
```

So how can I lengthen the 'second' member of b without completely redefining it as a class unrelated to a.

Also, solutions like resize don't work:

```
c = a()
resize(c.second, 100)
ValueError: Memory cannot be resized because this object doesn't own it
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't exactly a simple way to do this as ctypes Structures are made to be rather static (to match their c-counterparts). Anyways, you could subclass `ctypes.Structure` and do something like this as a function on that class:

```
def getUpdated(self, fieldName, fieldType):
    fieldsCopy = self._fields_
    found = False
    for idx, itm in enumerate(fieldsCopy):
        # find a matching field name

        i = list(itm) # can't modify a tuple
        if i[0] == fieldName:
            i[1] = fieldType
            fieldsCopy[idx] = tuple(i) # update the type with the new one
            found = True
            break # end the loop

    if not found: # fieldName wasn't in the field
        return False

    class TmpStructure(Structure):
        ''' we made a new structure type based off the original '''
        _pack_ = self._pack_
        _fields_ = fieldsCopy

    return TmpStructure # return the type, though we could probably 
                        # pass the values if needed and make a new instance
                        # of the new
```

`

Basically, we are returning a new type with a changed field type. This could be modified to also handle bitfields, `Structure` inheritance, and/or return instances instead of types. Though this should be enough to get you started.